# Jquery related problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have only one button and I mention what to do when user click on the button with the help of jQuery. but when I click then nothing happen just only postback happen. I don't want a postback.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="BBAWeb.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(showMessage);
            return false;
        });

        function showMessage() {
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow').html("Hello");
        }  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
        <div id="message">welcome to kolkata</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see my code and tell me what is wrong in it. I would like a suggestion.

Comment: are you sure the asp button control has that ID when it runs client side?  I'm not sure on this but I think I recall control IDs being entirely separate from HTML ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, when the button finally gets displayed on the page, asp.net will change the button id to more unique so it can manage everything better.

so your jquery $("btn") would not be able to find anything.

instead, just add a class, say, "myBtn" to your button and do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" CssClass="myBtn" />
```

and js:

```
<script>
$(".myBtn").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  showMessage();
});
</script>
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

`return false` should be inside the click event handler, but it is better to use e.preventDefault()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= btn.ClientId%>').click(showMessage);
});

function showMessage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message').fadeIn('slow').html("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the button selector to this:

```
$('#<%= btn.ClientId%>').click(showMessage);
```

And move the return false into the showMessage function.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this `$('#btn').click(showMessage);` jQuery tries to find button with ID "btn", but because you have a server control asp.net button, its ID is not rendered as "btn", instead ASP.NET adds a bunch of string to avoid duplicate ID.

So, in order for jQuery to be able to find your button, change your script to:

```
$('#<%= btn.ClientID %>').click(showMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do what you're trying to do, and a couple of reasons why your code isn't working.

First of all, if you want to prevent postback on an ASP.NET Button control, you should give it a client-side OnClick handler that returns `false`. You can set the handler with JavaScript (as you're doing), or you can set the control's OnClientClick property on the server side.

Secondly, if you use JavaScript to set the handler, you need to use the correct client-side ID of the Button. **The client-side ID of your Button is not necessarily what you've typed into the Button's `ID` attribute.** In this code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
```

the ID *"btn"* is only the **server-side** ID, which can be used in your C# code. The **client-side** ID is going to be rewritten to something like *"ctl00$MainContent$btn"*, so that's what needs to be in your JavaScript. You can access it by using `<%= btn.ClientID %>`, as others have pointed out:

```
$('#<%= btn.ClientID %>').click(showMessage);
```

If you're using .NET 4.0, you can also set `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the Button's attributes, and then `btn` will be used on both the server-side or the client-side.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

So, to sum up: Your `showMessage` function should look like this:

```
    function showMessage() {
        $('#message').fadeIn('slow').html("Hello");
        return false;
    }
```

And your other code should look like one of these:

1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(showMessage);
        return false;
    });
...
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

2.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= btn.ClientID %>').click(showMessage);
        return false;
    });
...
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
```

3.

```
//no $(document).ready needed
...
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="return showMessage()" />
```

Comment: @Corneliu - I know, but the OP had it in his code, so I left it in. The only thing I changed in `$(document).ready()` was the `<%= btn.ClientID %>`.